# mysql query to select rows without any relation

Tags: mysql

hi i have table a with column

```
id desc rate  rates_id

1   NYC  0.1    0001
2   NYC  0.25   0003
3   KYC  0.12   0001
4   KYC  0.15   0003
```

i need to display rows in this manner

```
desc  rate where rates_id = 0001  rate where rates_id=0003
NYC    0.1                        0.25
KYC    0.12                       0.15
```

i wroe this query but not working

```
SELECT desc,
       rate,
       (SELECT rate
        FROM   tablea p
        WHERE  rates_id LIKE '0003'
               AND p.desc = t.desc) AS rate2
FROM   tablea t
WHERE  rates_id LIKE '0001';
```

any suggesion ???

Comment: X.L.Ant thanks for quick reply but your query gives me rate1 column total null and few rate 2 values even though there are values present for both rates_id

Comment: Look at the fiddle, the sample data provided returns exactly the expected output you described. Is there some information you omitted in your question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT `desc`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rates_id = '0001' THEN rate ELSE NULL END) AS `rate where rates_id = 0001`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rates_id = '0003' THEN rate ELSE NULL END) AS `rate where rates_id = 0003`
FROM table a
GROUP BY `desc`
```

If you want to display only rows where there's at least one value, you can append the following to your query:

```
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN rates_id = '0001' THEN rate ELSE NULL END) IS NOT NULL
    OR MAX(CASE WHEN rates_id = '0003' THEN rate ELSE NULL END) IS NOT NULL
```

or filter directly on the relevant rates_id:

```
SELECT `desc`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rates_id = '0001' THEN rate ELSE NULL END) AS `rate where rates_id = 0001`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rates_id = '0003' THEN rate ELSE NULL END) AS `rate where rates_id = 0003`
FROM table a
WHERE rates_id IN ('0001', '0003')
GROUP BY `desc`
```

- [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/864e18/1/0) to see it working live

Comment: hi could you explain me why u used MAX , cant we get it done by using exists or some easy query???

Comment: If you don't use MAX, you'll get a row for each couple desc/rates_id, with only one value in column rate=0001 or rate=0003, the other column being null. Grouping them using MAX will merge all those values in only one row for each value of desc, discarding null values if another value is available.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your main query filters out the results for the sub query.

You can either select both rates as subselects.

```
SELECT distinct `desc`,
   (SELECT rate
    FROM   tablea p
    WHERE  rates_id LIKE '0001'
           AND p.`desc` = t.`desc`) AS rate1,
   (SELECT rate
    FROM   tablea p
    WHERE  rates_id LIKE '0003'
           AND p.`desc` = t.`desc`) AS rate2
FROM   tablea t;
```

heres the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1a35/2)

or you use `joins` to subeselect the rates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.`desc`, rate1.rate, rate2.rate
FROM tablea t
LEFT JOIN tablea rate1 ON t.`desc` = rate1.`desc` AND rate1.rates_id = '0001'
LEFT JOIN tablea rate2 ON t.`desc` = rate2.`desc` AND rate2.rates_id = '0003'
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1a35/5) for the joins

I would recommend you use `joins`, but you may want to use `EXPLAIN` for both queries and see what has the lower cost in your environment.

Comment: You have to `DISTINCT` to avoid same lines being displayed more than once.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Yes, you are right, I'll include it (currently building the SQL Fiddles)